# how remove css and html tags using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks for helping me do the css changes... :)

Now i want to do some changes to the below code. It is the html table code i believe...Using javascript, i want to remove the background color for this table which is white and it also has a border.

Also i want to remove 'onlyluxuryclothing' and 'Designer Clothing' text from the table.

I am posting link to screenshot of the table on how it looks and what i want to do with it,

[screenshot](http://superbabyboutique.com/screenshot.jpg)
[code](http://superbabyboutique.com/tablecode.txt)

Also i have attached link to the code...if you can let me know the javascript to remove the white background, border of the table and the text i mentioned above. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want to remove complete code or any code block. If complete code is unused just comment out in page or delete from source page.

Comment: What specifically do you want to remove, just the `<style>` attribute? Which one, the outer one (with the invalid HTML comments inside of it) or the inner one, wrapped with the invalid HTML comments? And why do you want to force every client to download a portion of a document that you then make their browser remove? If you don't want it in the document, remove it from the document on the server-side to avoid wasting time and bandwidth. Also, without undertaking any research yourself to investigate how to do this, are you sure you'll understand any posted solutions?

Comment: Also, please stop putting JS/CSS inside HTML comments...

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `.remove()` function for this:

```
$('style').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
$(selector).removeAttr( 'style' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var styleTags = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
  for (var i=0, max = styleTags .length; i < max; i++) {
    styleTags [i].parentNode.removeChild(styleTags [i]);
  }
```

It will remove all `style` tags

Answer (score 0):

You should put your css in an external file and link it to your `html` file.
To minimize spacing to your file. (A good coding standard).

Using the `<link>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Some Title</title>

    <!-- Put this inside your head tag in html -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Your html content goes here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And if you want to remove some styles in your tags, use the JQUERY `removeAttr` attribute.

**Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").removeAttr("style");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p style="font-size:120%;color:red">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="font-weight:bold;color:blue">This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Remove the style attribute from all p elements</button>

</body>
</html>
```

*Reference Link :* [removeAttr Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_removeattr)

For my own perspective, it will take so much time by removing all the styles of your tags using JQUERY. If you want to remove all the styles, just remove the `link` tag element that contains all your css files.

**OTHER OPTION** or you could use the answers from other developers.

```
By using jquery
//It will remove the style element.
$("style").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('style').detach();
});
```

Or this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('style').remove();
});
```

Here you have all the info:
For [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
And for [Detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Say if works for you, please :)

Answer (score 0):

u can use this to remove scripts or styles

```
msg = $('<div>' + msg + '</div>'); msg.find('script, style').remove(); msg = msg.html();
```

or for any tags

```
msg.replace(/<script[^>]*?>.*?<\/script>/gi, '').
                     replace(/<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>/gi, '').
                     replace(/<style[^>]*?>.*?<\/style>/gi, '').
                     replace(/<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>/gi, '').
           replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
```